# How can I test if a method has worked or not?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, boolean

Using the code below, I need to test whether or not the method has been successful in working, and then print "false" if the method has not been successful.

```
private void doShowBorrower()
    {
        boolean found = false;
        System.out.println("Enter Library Number to Search: ");
        String borrowerLibraryNumber = myScanner.next();
        borrowerList.getBorrower(borrowerLibraryNumber);
    }
```

I was thinking about using a boolean 'found' which I can set to be true if the method worked properly, and then if it's still false then to print "false".

However, I'm not sure how to implement this. I'm assuming you need to use loops, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: jut look if it does what do you expect

Comment: What are checking the success of? If `getBorrower` got something or if the user input a library number?

Comment: Did you consider `return`ing a `boolean` that indicates success / failure?

Comment: You should define what constitutes "successful in working" and work from there. It could mean that the method completed without an exception or that a borrower was found (or not) just as two possibilities,

Comment: @5gon12eder That's exactly what I want to do, but how can I change the state of the boolean depending on if the method succeeds or not?

Comment: Basically I'm searching for a specific string using a method in another class, if it finds it I want to return true, if it doesn't find it I want to return false.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I'm checking whether or not getBorrower found the string that the user inputted.

Comment: @J.Brown Then `getBorrower` should return true or false depending on if it found it. Then in your method above you'd just `return borrowerList.getBorrower(borrowerLibraryNumber);` and make it `private boolean`

Comment: The thing is I don't just want to return the boolean, I want to test whether the boolean is true or not and then output a string based on whether it is true or false. I've tried throwing     borrowerList.getBorrower(borrowerLibraryNumber); into an if statement but that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question depends on what `borrowerList.getBorrower(borrowerLibraryNumber)` returns.

- If `borrowerList.getBorrower(borrowerLibraryNumber)` call returns an object, you can check for Null and if the returned object is null, then you can set the flag to true
- If `borrowerList.getBorrower(borrowerLibraryNumber)` call throws an exception when requested object is not found, then you can catch the exception and set the flag to true with in catch block.

Comment: The method returns a number of string that are associated with an object, assuming the object actually exists (which is checked by comparing borrowerLibraryNumber and the LibraryNumber associated with the specific borrower.)

Comment: Then  if the method returns at least one string you can assume as true.

Comment: Yeah the true isn't the problem. It's the false that's the problem. When the method doesn't return a string i.e. an input number that doesn't match to a borrower. I need to print a statement saying "This number does not correspond to a borrower. "

Comment: When method does not return any string, check if the array or list returned is null or empty